# How to speed up selenium Python web crawler

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I have a web crawler built by selenium Python for pages that use JavaScript for content. The crawler works well, but it takes a lot of time to end (sometimes takes a couple of days!!). How can I speed up and make it faster?

***Hint:***

- The crawler extracts urls, forms, and events.
- I cannot put the source code of the crawler because it's a long code.

Thanks.

Comment: try to use multi-treading

Comment: Also if you haven't already use webdriver waits instead of any time.sleep() .

Comment: @Vova I read multiple resources that indicate it's unsafe. So, I'm afraid to use it.

Comment: @A.. without any idea about what you are doing, we can only provide general hints. This includes multi-threading, which is not by default unsafe, but completely depends on your usage. See [how to make your selenium tests faster](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-make-your-selenium-tests-faster-alex-siminiuc/)  or [selenium speed scraping](https://medium.com/@winston.smith.spb/python-selenium-speed-scraping-45bda525e42) for general ways to make it faster.

Comment: @Thymen  I extract URLs, forms, and events, and then I used these data to fuzz the app.